# Statement object using:

Tags: java, jdbc

I have Java code that connects to an SQL server DB but I cannot access the DB from the Java app. When I compiled the connection was successfully reported but I cannot execute any SQL statement. The error is that:

run:

```
The SQL connection was successful.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement cannot be cast to java.beans.Statement
        at project.getConnection.connection(getConnection.java:73)
        at project.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

here is the line 73 if i remove the (Statement)

```
 s = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to import `javax.sql.Statement`, not `java.beans.Statement`.

Comment: sorry i run my java code after connecting to Db but i resived this error:

run:
The SQL connection was successful.
JDBC Driver error:Invalid object name 'dbo.categories'.

categories is an entity in my sql server DB
thanks

Comment: @Aida That's a completely different problem. You should post it as a new question if you need help resolving it.